# Replace foreign key dropdown with textbox with add/edit icon - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-actions

Related to foreign key fields in the Django Admin, the default display 
element is a drop down list box containing all of the foreign key 
items from the related model.  I my app it will contain thousands of items and I am looking to change the admin interface and have it use a text box instead of the populated drop down.

Looking for textbox with add/edit icon next to it, so that we dont get populated values, we just directly add or edit.

Is there any way around to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use custom Form and realize custom Widget on this form field. (I use for this desicion 3rd party library [django_select2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django-Select2/4.3.1))

```
from django import forms
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget


class KeyWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    model = ModelToKey
    search_fields = ['field__icontains']

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return u'{}'.format(obj.field)


class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelWithKey
        fields = ('foreign_key_field')
        widgets = {
            'foreign_key_field': KeyWidget(attrs={'style': 'width:550px'}),
            }
```

In also you can overload Form `__init__` for customize queryset of objects for choosing in this field.

Comment: If `django_select2` is not part of the Django package, maybe you should precise which package to install and which are the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `raw_id_fields`

```py
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("newspaper", )
```

- By default, Django’s admin uses a select-box interface (<select>)
  for fields that are **ForeignKey**. Sometimes you don’t want to incur
  the overhead of having to select all the related instances to display
  in the drop-down.
- `raw_id_fields` is a list of fields you would like to change into an
  **Input** widget for either a **ForeignKey** or **ManyToManyField**:

---

**NOTE**: The **raw_id_fields Input** widget should contain a primary key if the field is a **ForeignKey** or a *comma separated list* of values if the field is a **ManyToManyField**. The **raw_id_fields** widget shows a magnifying glass button next to the field which allows users to search for and select a value:

You can read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)